# Embedding Javascript in PDF to force links to open in new window

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

We are generating PDFs that are displayed on certain pages of our web app. The PDFs are displayed in iframes within the page. If a user clicks a link inside one of the PDFs on Internet Explorer with Acrobat installed, it loads the link in the iframe, which breaks the user experience.

What I would like to accomplish is to embed Javascript in the PDF so any links that are clicked in the PDF are opened in a new window. I tried embedding the following code in the PDF:

```
/Type /Action
/S /JavaScript
/JS (app.openInPlace = false;)
```

The resulting PDFs continue to open links in place. I am using the utility functions from [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/) to embed the Javascript inside the PDFs.

It also just occurred to me that it might not be possible to open a link from a PDF in a new window from within an iframe.

Comment: any news about this? is it possible to open a link in new window from a PDF or not?

Comment: I don't think I ever resolved this issue.